# Multiple results from activity to fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity, callback

I've got a question about results/callback from activities to fragments.
Until now I have a fragment which calls a camera activity to scan QR Codes. So I start the activity from the fragment with `startActivityForResult`. If a QR Code is successfully scanned I get a callback `Intent` which is handled in `onActivityResult`.
This works perfectly.

Now I want to handle multiple scanns. In detail that means, that every successfully scan should call the `onActivityResult` function without closing the activity. The problem which I got at this point is, that `onActivityResult` is only called if I call `finish()` in the camera activity.

So my question is, how can I call `onActivityResult` multiple times with or without calling `finish()` but without closing the activity? Or is there another way to handle callbacks from activities to fragments?

This is my fragment code:

```kotlin
class ScanFragment : Fragment() {

    private val CHECKIN_CODE = 0
    private val CHECKOUT_CODE = 1

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): LeadScanFragment = LeadScanFragment()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lead_scan, container, false)

        view.checkin.setOnClickListener {view ->
            val intent = Intent(activity, CodeScannerActivity::class.java)
            startActivityForResult(intent, CHECKIN_CODE)
        }

        view.checkout.setOnClickListener {view ->
            val intent = Intent(activity, CodeScannerActivity::class.java)
            startActivityForResult(intent, CHECKOUT_CODE)
        }

        return view
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == CHECKIN_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val returnString = data!!.getStringExtra("hash")
                Log.d("scaned in", returnString)
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == CHECKOUT_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val returnString = data!!.getStringExtra("hash")
                Log.d("scaned out", returnString)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the camera activity code:

```kotlin
class CodeScannerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val requestCodeCameraPermission = 1001
    private lateinit var cameraSource: CameraSource
    private lateinit var detector: BarcodeDetector

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_code_scanner)

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@CodeScannerActivity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            askForCameraPermission()
        } else {
            setup()
        }
    }

    private fun setup() {
        detector = BarcodeDetector.Builder(this@CodeScannerActivity).build()
        cameraSource = CameraSource.Builder(this@CodeScannerActivity, detector).setAutoFocusEnabled(true).build()

        cameraSurfaceView.holder.addCallback(surfaceCallback)
        detector.setProcessor(processor)
    }

    private fun askForCameraPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@CodeScannerActivity, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), requestCodeCameraPermission)
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        if(requestCode == requestCodeCameraPermission && grantResults.isNotEmpty()) {
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                setup()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Permission denied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    private val surfaceCallback = object : SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        override fun surfaceCreated(surfaceHolder: SurfaceHolder?) {
            try {
                cameraSource.start(surfaceHolder)
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        override fun surfaceChanged(p0: SurfaceHolder?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

        }

        override fun surfaceDestroyed(p0: SurfaceHolder?) {
            cameraSource.stop()
        }
    }

    private val processor = object : Detector.Processor<Barcode> {
        override fun release() {

        }

        override fun receiveDetections(detections: Detector.Detections<Barcode>?) {
            val intent = Intent()

            if(detections != null && detections.detectedItems.isNotEmpty()) {
                val qrCodes: SparseArray<Barcode> = detections.detectedItems
                val code = qrCodes.valueAt(0)

                intent.putExtra("hash", code.displayValue)
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
                finish()
            } else {
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, intent)
                finish()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`receiveDetections` inside the `processor` in the lower area of the camera activity code is where the callback Intent is send back to `onActivityResult`.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the scanner `Activity` send a local broadcast `Intent` to forward "results" to the calling `Fragment`. The `Fragment` (or its hosting `Activity`) should set a listener to listen for the broadcast "results". In this way you could perform multiple scans and send each result back to the underlying `Activity`.